# iphone - UIImageView zoom programmatically

Tags: iphone, animation

Using CATransition, can I zoom an image view in iPhone?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a UIScrollView and its zoomToRect: method.

See:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: I'm asking how to zoom an image view by writing code. For example, if the image view size is 100x100, i want to change the image view size to 150x150 and keep the center constant.

Comment: you put your image in a UIScrollView and zoom programmatically with the mentioned zoomToRect: method. It will also animate this "zoom-progress" if you want.

Comment: @Satyam svv thats the only way, you can't zoom an UIImageView, but you can zoom a UIScrollView (or WebView)

Answer (score 0):

Or... you should use a UIWebView (thats what I did in "Seriously Good! Gluten Free"). You can put in images in HTML code and you get all of the zoom, pan and etc for free! :) And it will work with all versions of the SDK.

Comment: I'm asking how to zoom an image view by writing code. For example, if the image view size is 100x100, i want to change the image view size to 150x150 and keep the center constant.